# Postgresql 13, why aren't these indexes working at all? I'm using pg_trgm correctly?

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, indexing

Postgresql 13, I have this query:

```sql
SELECT
    "id",
    "first_name",
    "last_name",
    "code"
FROM
    "players"
WHERE
    ( team_id = 3 )
    AND (
        lower(code) LIKE 'lushijo'
    OR
        lower(replace(last_name||first_name,' ','')) LIKE '%lushijo%'
    )
LIMIT 15
```

I also have these indexes:

```sql
CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm;

CREATE INDEX players_lower_code_trgm ON players USING gin (lower(code) gin_trgm_ops);

CREATE INDEX players_lower_replace_last_first_name_trgm ON players using gin (lower(replace(last_name||first_name,' ','')) gin_trgm_ops);
```

If I explain that query I see it's not using indexes at all:

```
Limit  (cost=0.00..115.68 rows=15 width=40)
  ->  Seq Scan on players player  (cost=0.00..39330.76 rows=5100 width=40)
        Filter: ((team_id = 3) AND ((lower(code) ~~ 'lushijo'::text) OR (lower(replace((last_name || first_name), ' '::text, ''::text)) ~~ '%lushijo%'::text)))
```

**Why?**

Comment: You don't need to use `lower()` with a trigram index

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, thanks this is the problem. It works now.

Answer (score 1):

Generally I would say that nesting transformations of data (for example the `lower` and the `replace` function) within an index should be avoided.

Instead create the columns first and then create your indexes:

```
CREATE TABLE players_transformed AS
    SELECT 
        id,
        team_id,
        first_name,
        last_name,
        REPLACE(last_name || first_name, ' ', '') AS full_name,
        code
    FROM players;
```

Then create your indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX ON players_transformed (team_id);
CREATE INDEX ON players_transformed USING gin (code, gin_trgm_ops);
CREATE INDEX ON players_transformed USING gin (full_name, gin_trgm_ops);
```

Then run a slightly altered query, using ILIKE (which is case insensitive so we can avoid the `lower` function altogether):

```
SELECT 
    id,
    code,
    first_name,
    last_name,
    code
FROM players
WHERE 
    team_id = 3 
    AND (
        code ILIKE '%lushijo%'
        OR
        full_name ILIKE '%lushijo%'
    )
LIMIT 15;
```

Even with all of the above advice, PostgreSQL will still choose the most appropriate explain plan for the given query and this explain plan can be influenced by a number of factors - for example the number of rows in the table. So I cannot guarantee that the executor will 100% use the indexes created. Perhaps you could share more information about table size and the full table schema? As this would help with fully optimising your query.